# Python signal SIGQUIT doesn't works

Tags: python, signals, macos-mojave

As intended signals work perfectly when i invoke **SIGINT(2)** and **SIGTERM(15)**, but when I invoke **SIGQUIT(3)** by issuing following command `kill -3 script_pid` *signal_handler* is not invoked.
I know that **signal.SIGKILL** *cannot be caught, blocked, or ignored* ([as per docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html#signal.SIGKILL)), is it same for SIGQUIT ?

Note : I'm using Python3.6 in a MacOS environment.

```
def signal_handler(signal_num, frame):
    print(f"Got Signal {signal_num}!")
    sys.exit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # INTERRUPT (2) Works !
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handler=signal_handler)
    # TERM (15) Works !
    signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, handler=signal_handler)
    # QUIT (3) Doesn't Works !
    signal.signal(signal.SIGQUIT, handler=signal_handler)

    print('PID :', os.getpid())

    # wait in an endless loop for signals
    while True:
        print('Waiting...')
        time.sleep(3)
```

Comment: It worked as expected on my system.

Comment: Well mine doesn't ! What OS are you using ?

Comment: I'm using Linux.

Comment: Well mine is a macos ! Does it makes a difference ?

Comment: I just tried it also on MacOS, works the same as Linux.

`Remainder of file ignored
PID : 93286
Waiting...
Waiting...
Waiting...
Waiting...
Waiting...
Got Signal 3!
`

Comment: Well it doesn't works in my system ! Although rest signal works perfectly . What else should i provide to know root cause ?

Comment: Hard to tell from here, could be something specific to your shell or system. This Python does work fine for me, however.

Comment: Ahh Thanks ! *could be something specific to your shell* Solves my problem ! I was running my script from pycharm terminal, so instead i tried from normal os terminal and it worked. Although still can't get why it doesn't works from pycharm terminal .

Comment: Ah, PyCharm may be setting another handler for that.

Comment: Yeah think so ! anyway Thanks !!

Comment: Only `SIGKILL` and `SIGSTOP` are special (can’t be caught, blocked, or ignored).